# How to make TigerGraph start at reboot? Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, startup, reboot

I've just installed TigerGraph :

```
===============================================================
Congratulations! Installation Finished! 
===============================================================

[PROGRESS]: 08:39:55 Start tigergraph service, this may take a while ... 
Adding directories to PATH:
PATH += /home/raphy/emsdk
PATH += /home/raphy/emsdk/upstream/emscripten

Setting environment variables:
PATH = /home/raphy/emsdk:/home/raphy/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
EMSDK = /home/raphy/emsdk
EM_CONFIG = /home/raphy/emsdk/.emscripten
[   Info] Starting EXE
[   Info] Starting CTRL
[   Info] Generating config files to all machines
[   Info] Successfully applied configuration change. Please restart services to make it effective immediately.
[   Info] Initializing KAFKA
[   Info] Starting EXE
[   Info] Starting CTRL
[   Info] Starting ZK ETCD DICT KAFKA ADMIN GSE NGINX GPE RESTPP KAFKASTRM-LL KAFKACONN TS3SERV GSQL TS3 IFM GUI
[   Info] Applying config
[Warning] No difference from staging config, config apply is skipped.
[   Info] Successfully applied configuration change. Please restart services to make it effective immediately.
[   Info] Cluster is initialized successfully
===============================================================
TigerGraph is successfully started! 
===============================================================

Adding directories to PATH:
PATH += /home/raphy/emsdk
PATH += /home/raphy/emsdk/upstream/emscripten

Setting environment variables:
PATH = /home/raphy/emsdk:/home/raphy/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
EMSDK = /home/raphy/emsdk
EM_CONFIG = /home/raphy/emsdk/.emscripten
[NOTE    ]: Time synchronization check passed 
Thank you for using TigerGraph platform!
[NOTE    ]: Please login to node m1 (127.0.0.1) of the platform to continue. 
[NOTE    ]: The TigerGraph user: raphy
```

But once I reboot Ubuntu 20.04, TigerGraph doesn't start

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ sudo netstat -ntpl
[sudo] password for raphy: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5582          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp        0      0 10.65.116.1:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2922/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5269            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1354/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1581/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1580/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5400            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71974/tg_dbs_restd  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      72076/tg_infr_ts3m  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:19001         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      72076/tg_infr_ts3m  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1625/tor            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5500            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71974/tg_dbs_restd  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/i2pd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15037           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/i2pd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7070          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/i2pd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4447          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/i2pd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:14240           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71940/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71897/etcd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5280            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20001         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71897/etcd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:14242         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      72329/tg_app_guid   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71940/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7656          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1621/i2pd           
tcp6       0      0 :::9166                 :::*                    LISTEN      72293/tg_infr_ifmd  
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5582                :::*                    LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp6       0      0 :::9167                 :::*                    LISTEN      72293/tg_infr_ifmd  
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:30002         :::*                    LISTEN      43983/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30003                :::*                    LISTEN      72030/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::35507                :::*                    LISTEN      43896/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::30004                :::*                    LISTEN      71986/java          
tcp6       0      0 fd42:2159:3d69:bcae::53 :::*                    LISTEN      2922/dnsmasq        
tcp6       0      0 :::5269                 :::*                    LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1581/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1580/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:12471         :::*                    LISTEN      71920/tg_infr_admin 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:12471         :::*                    LISTEN      71920/tg_infr_admin 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:12471         :::*                    LISTEN      71920/tg_infr_admin 
tcp6       0      0 :::9177                 :::*                    LISTEN      43865/tg_infr_exed  
tcp6       0      0 :::41305                :::*                    LISTEN      2637/lxd            
tcp6       0      0 :::9178                 :::*                    LISTEN      43865/tg_infr_exed  
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8123          :::*                    LISTEN      72161/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::19999                :::*                    LISTEN      43896/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::5280                 :::*                    LISTEN      1549/lua5.2         
tcp6       0      0 :::9188                 :::*                    LISTEN      43881/tg_infr_ctrld 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:17797         :::*                    LISTEN      71906/tg_infr_dictd 
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:17797         :::*                    LISTEN      71906/tg_infr_dictd 
tcp6       0      0 :::5222                 :::*                    LISTEN      1549/lua5.2
```

And it seems working fine....:

[image]

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ ps xa | grep tigergraph
  43865 ?        Ssl    3:37 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_infr_exed -c /home/raphy/.tg.cfg --daemon=true
  43881 ?        Sl     0:12 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_infr_ctrld -c /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/tg.cfg
  43896 ?        Sl     0:18 java -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/home/raphy/tigergraph/log/zk -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/zk/conf/log4j.properties -cp /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/classes:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../build/classes:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../zookeeper-server/target/lib/*.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/zookeeper-prometheus-metrics-3.6.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/snappy-java-1.1.7.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/simpleclient_servlet-0.6.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/simpleclient_hotspot-0.6.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/simpleclient_common-0.6.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/simpleclient-0.6.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-transport-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-resolver-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-handler-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-common-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-codec-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/netty-buffer-4.1.63.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/metrics-core-3.2.5.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jline-2.14.6.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-util-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-servlet-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-server-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-security-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-io-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jetty-http-9.4.39.v20210325.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jackson-databind-2.10.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jackson-core-2.10.5.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/jackson-annotations-2.10.5.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../lib/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../zookeeper-*.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../zookeeper-server/src/main/resources/lib/*.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/zk/bin/../conf: -Xmx4096m -Djute.maxbuffer=8388608 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/zk/conf/zoo.cfg
  43983 ?        Sl     1:52 java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xlog:gc*:file=/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=102400 -Dkafka.logs.dir=/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/kafka/conf/log4j.properties -cp /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.5.1-sources.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.10.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/tg-kafka-connect-fs-1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/tg-kafka-connect-wrapper-1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/tg-kafka-stream-loading-log-1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.8.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.8.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.4-7.jar kafka.Kafka /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/kafka/conf/server.properties
  71897 ?        Sl     0:24 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/etcd/etcd --config-file /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/etcd/conf/etcd.cfg
  71906 ?        Sl     0:28 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_infr_dictd -c /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/tg.cfg --replica 1
  71920 ?        Sl     0:11 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_infr_admind -c /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/tg.cfg --replica 1
  71939 ?        Sl     0:07 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_dbs_gsed --config /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/tg.cfg --partition 1 --replica 1
  71940 ?        S      0:00 nginx: master process /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/nginx/sbin/nginx -p /home/raphy/tigergraph/log/nginx -c /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
  71966 ?        Sl     0:28 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_dbs_gped --config /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/tg.cfg --partition 1 --replica 1
  71974 ?        Sl     8:14 /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/bin/tg_dbs_restd --config /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/tg.cfg --replica 1
  71986 ?        Sl     0:31 java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dkafka.logs.dir=/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/raphy/tigergraph/data/configs/kafka/stream/conf/log4j.properties -cp /home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/libs:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/plugins:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-paranamer-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.10.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.22.0-CR2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-hk2-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.28.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-client-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.4.24.v20191120.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-2.5.1-sources.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-scala_2.12-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-test-utils-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-2.5.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.6.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-buffer-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-resolver-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.50.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/paranamer-2.8.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.12.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.18.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-java8-compat_2.12-0.9.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.10.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.2.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/tg-kafka-connect-fs-1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/tg-kafka-connect-wrapper-1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/tg-kafka-stream-loading-log-1.0.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.5.8.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-jute-3.5.8.jar:/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/kafka/bin/../libs/zstd-jni-1.4.4-7.jar com.tigergraph.kafka.stream.loadinglog.LogAggregation -t loading-log -p 30004 -d /home/raphy/tigergraph/data/kafkastrm-ll -s 127.0.0.1:30002
  72030 ?        Sl     0:39 java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseG1GC
```

I rebooted Ubuntu 20.04 and now TigerGraph 's process are gone, they are not running anymore, after reboot:

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ ps xa | grep tigergraph
   8625 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto tigergraph
(base) raphy@pc:~$
```

So.... problem is that if I reboot Ubuntu 20.04, TigerGraph processes do not start at reboot

But after rebooting, TigerGraph's processes seem gone

```
raphy@pc:~/tigergraph/app/cmd$ ./gadmin restart
[   Note] Restart the service(s)? (y/N)y
[   Info] Stopping DICT ADMIN GSE NGINX GPE RESTPP KAFKASTRM-LL KAFKACONN TS3SERV GSQL TS3 GUI
[  Error] ConnectionClosed (Failed to make RPC call to CTRL)

raphy@pc:~/tigergraph/app/cmd$ ./gssh
/home/raphy/tigergraph/app/3.3.0/cmd/gssh: line 18: gadmin:   
command not found
Can't find ssh config file: /ssh/ssh_config
```

How to make TigerGraph start at reboot?

Comment: Is it a systemd service? If so just run ```sudo systemctl enable <name_of_service>```. If it ain't such then you will have to create a systemd service for it and run the above command to have it restart on system reboot.

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeUdosen. After trying few times to create a systemd service, (it requires java), I decided to switched to the Docker Image . It seems working fine.